# Stopping/removing everything then changing scene

Tags: actionscript-3

I am making a shooting game and when i die it will not remove the child's it just freezes them on the screen. I would like to be able to stop all of the action then remove and change screens afterwards.

```
    var gunLength:uint = 90;
    var bullets:Array = new Array();
    var bulletSpeed:uint = 20;
    var baddies:Array = new Array();
    var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000);
    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, addBaddie);
    timer.start();
    var lives:Number = 0;

    stop();

    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, aimGun);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, fireGun);
    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveObjects);

    function addBaddie(evt:TimerEvent):void {
        var baddie:Baddie = new Baddie();
        var side:Number = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 4);
        if (side == 1) {
            baddie.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
            baddie.y = - baddie.height;
        } else if (side == 2) {
            baddie.x = stage.stageWidth + baddie.width;
            baddie.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
        } else if (side == 3) {
            baddie.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
            baddie.y = stage.stageHeight + baddie.height;
        } else if (side == 4) {
            baddie.x = - baddie.width
            baddie.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
        }
        baddie.angle = getAngle(baddie.x, baddie.y, gun.x, gun.y);
        baddie.speed = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 15);
        addChild(baddie);
        baddies.push(baddie);
    }

    function fireGun(evt:MouseEvent) {
        var bullet:Bullet = new Bullet();
        bullet.rotation = gun.rotation;
        bullet.x = gun.x + Math.cos(deg2rad(gun.rotation)) * gunLength;
        bullet.y = gun.y + Math.sin(deg2rad(gun.rotation)) * gunLength;
        addChild(bullet);
        bullets.push(bullet);
    }

    function moveObjects(evt:Event):void {
        moveBullets();
        moveBaddies();
    }

    function moveBullets():void {
        for (var i:int = 0; i < bullets.length; i++) {
            var dx = Math.cos(deg2rad(bullets[i].rotation)) * bulletSpeed;
            var dy = Math.sin(deg2rad(bullets[i].rotation)) * bulletSpeed;
            bullets[i].x += dx;
            bullets[i].y += dy;
        }
    }

    function moveBaddies():void {
        for (var i:int = 0; i < baddies.length; i++) {
            var dx = Math.cos(deg2rad(baddies[i].angle)) * baddies[i].speed;
            var dy = Math.sin(deg2rad(baddies[i].angle)) * baddies[i].speed;
            baddies[i].x += dx;
            baddies[i].y += dy;
            if (baddies[i].hitTestPoint(gun.x, gun.y, true)) {
                removeChild(baddies[i]);
                baddies.splice(i, 1);
                loseLife();
                lives -= 1;
                if(lives < 1){
                    gotoAndStop(1,"Dead");              
                    for each(var gun:Gun in gun){
                        removeChild(gun)
                    }

                    lives--;
                    trace("Lives = " + lives);
                }

            } else {
                checkForHit(baddies[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    function checkForHit(baddie:Baddie):void {
        for (var i:int = 0; i < bullets.length; i++) {
            if (baddie.hitTestPoint(bullets[i].x, bullets[i].y, true)) {
                removeChild(baddie);
                baddies.splice(baddies.indexOf(baddie), 1);

            }
        }
    }

    function loseLife():void {
    }

    function aimGun(evt:Event):void {
        gun.rotation = getAngle(gun.x, gun.y, mouseX, mouseY);
        var distance:Number = getDistance(gun.x, gun.y, mouseX, mouseY);
        var adjDistance:Number = distance / 12 - 7;
    }

    function getAngle(x1:Number, y1:Number, x2:Number, y2:Number):Number {
        var radians:Number = Math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1);
        return rad2deg(radians);
    }

    function getDistance(x1:Number, y1:Number, x2:Number, y2:Number):Number {
        var dx:Number = x2 - x1;
        var dy:Number = y2 - y1;
        return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    }

    function rad2deg(rad:Number):Number {
        return rad * (180 / Math.PI);
    }

    function deg2rad(deg:Number):Number {
        return deg * (Math.PI/180);
    }

    var target:MovieClip;

    initialiseCursor();

    function initialiseCursor():void {
        Mouse.hide();
        target = new Target();
        target.x = mouseX;
        target.y = mouseY;
        target.mouseEnabled = false;
        addChild(target);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, targetMove);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, targetDown);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, targetUp);
    }

    function targetMove(evt:MouseEvent):void {
        target.x = this.mouseX;
        target.y = this.mouseY;
    }


    function targetDown(evt:MouseEvent):void {
        target.gotoAndStop(2);
    }

    function targetUp(evt:MouseEvent):void {
        target.gotoAndStop(1);
    }
```

Comment: Are you removing the baddies? I see that you are only removing the gun objects when dead.

Comment: you should change this code, and break it into classes, and then you can add all the objects of classes on screens, and when it comes to removing, it is very easy for you to remove everything.

Other approach is that you can make it screenwise (add all the things in one main container), means when you remove screen, everything will be removed from the stage.

Comment: Read this quick tutorial on Garbage Collection in AS3
http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/workflow/quick-tip-understanding-garbage-collection-in-as3/

<p>And then read this if you want a more detailed look at it:
<p>http://tomgabob.blogspot.ca/2009/11/as3-memory-management.html